# AWS S3 Android SDK: Get path of uploaded file

Tags: android, amazon-s3, filepath

I'm following the steps here for uploading a file to AWS S3
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

Is there any way through the SDK to get the path of the file I just uploaded?

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the URL by yourself, using the bucket and the file name you used in the upload request.

I mean for example if your bucket is `AMAZON_S3_BUCKET` and your file is named `myfile`:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/AMAZON_S3_BUCKET/myfile
```

or

```
https://AMAZON_S3_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile
```

Or if you are using some region like `Regions.US_WEST_2` then The URL will be different depending on which region your bucket is in

```
https://AMAZON_S3_BUCKET.YOUR_BUCKET_REGION.amazonaws.com/myfile
```

Comment: I found regions and endpoints here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Comment: @Mike6679 yes you should see which one your bucket is in and use it in the url